# Unity Object reference is lost

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set up a save system for my voxel game. Everything works fine except there's a low chance (like 1/8) of the save file not saving due to a System.NullReferenceException.

I've looked over the code many times and confused why this exception is **sometimes** thrown. At no point in the game am I setting a RegionData reference to null. I can press 'Save' again, and everything will likely work fine.

```cs
    [MessagePackObject]
    public class RegionData
    {
        [Key(0)]
        public Vector2Int Position { get; set; } = new Vector2Int(0, 0);
        [Key(1)]
        public ChunkData[][] Chunks { get; set; }
        
        // Used when opening a saved region data.
        public RegionData()
        {
            
        }

        // Used when creating a new region data.
        public RegionData(Vector2Int regionPosition)
        {
            Position = regionPosition;
            Chunks = Utilities.CreateJaggedArray<ChunkData[][]>(16, 16);
        }
    }

    public class RegionSaver
    {
        readonly List<RegionData> pendingRegions;
        readonly Queue<RegionData> regionsReady;
        static readonly int SaveDelay = 4000;
        
        public RegionSaver()
        {
            pendingRegions = new List<RegionData>(10);
            regionsReady = new Queue<RegionData>(10);
            SaveRegionsFromQueue();
        }

        public async Task AddRegionData(RegionData regionData)
        {
            if (pendingRegions.Contains(regionData))
                return;           
            
            pendingRegions.Add(regionData);

            await Task.Delay(SaveDelay).ConfigureAwait(false);
            
            if (pendingRegions.Contains(regionData))
            {
                regionsReady.Enqueue(regionData);
                pendingRegions.Remove(regionData);
            }
        }

        // Infinite loop that saves Regions that have been pushed to the queue.
        async void SaveRegionsFromQueue()
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    while (regionsReady.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var regionData = regionsReady.Dequeue();
                        // This is were 'regionData' is sometimes null.

                        try
                        {
                            await SaveRegion(regionData).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Debug.LogError($"Error whiles trying to save Region.\nException: {e}");
                        }
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1f)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            });
        }
        
        async Task SaveRegion(RegionData regionData)
        {                       
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(
                    string.Format(RegionLoader.RegionDataFilePath, regionData.Position.x, regionData.Position.y)))
            {
                await MessagePackSerializer.SerializeAsync(fileStream, regionData, Utilities.Lz4Options)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }  
        }
    }
```

How the AddRegionData method is invoked. `Task.Run(() => chunkHandler.RegionSaver.AddRegionData(regionData));`

Comment: Might not be the issue, but: if the default constructor for `RegionData` is used rather than the parameterized version, `Chunks` is null. I'd set a breakpoint in that constructor and see if/when it's called, which could happen as part of scene loading & deserialization.

Comment: I don't believe that would be the issue as the RegionData.Chunks are used to generate the voxel data, which is perfectly generated in the scene. Rider also shows that there are no references to the default constructor. No breakpoint triggered

Comment: Can't you just guarantee it will be valid before the operation happens? For example, `if(reference == null) reference = GetReference()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed my problem. Replacing Queue and List, which I already replaced with a Dictionary, with a [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netcore-3.1#:%7E:text=%20Concurrent%20Queue%3CT%3E%20Class%20%201%20Constructors.%20Initializes,to%20an%20Array%2C%20starting%20at%20a...%20More%20) and [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) results in no null references. I didn't know concurrency could cause such weird problems.